# Why doesn't my range facet work?

Tags: coveo

When I add a Coveo Numeric Facet Range facet to my search page, it displays a list of values, not a list of ranges as I would expect.

[image: 2019-08-22_1231]

Is there a way to get it to show ranges instead of individual values?

Comment: @downvoter: please add a comment so I can improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a computed field, the field must be configured as a numeric type to use the numeric facet range facets.

To do this, update the `ReturnType` on the computed field's class to return `"Number"` and it will work.